# How do I get Fibonacci numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript

Given input = `[1,2,4]` return `[1,2]`, or if no fibonacci numbers return `[]`, `[1,1,2]` should return `[1,2]`;

I know you can check whether a number is in the fibonacci sequence with this code:

```
function isSquare(n) {
    return n > 0 && Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
};

//Equation modified from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/

function isFibonacci(numberToCheck)    
{
    // numberToCheck is Fibinacci if one of 5*n*n + 4 or 5*n*n - 4 or both
    // is a perferct square
    return isPerfectSquare(5*numberToCheck*numberToCheck + 4) ||
           isPerfectSquare(5*numberToCheck*numberToCheck - 4);    
}
```

But I don’t know how to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Try `Array.filter` - The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function). [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: you can use [`.filter(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out numbers that aren't fibonacci numbers. Also, you are calling `isPerfectSquare` in that `isFibonacci` function but you have named your square-checking function as `isSquare` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.from(new Set(arr))` Removes duplicates from the original array

`let newArr = [];` Defining the new array

`for ( let i = 0; i < arrD.length; i++ )` Loop every number of `arrD`, `arrD[i]` accesses a number in the array

`if(fib(arrD[i])) { newArr.push(arrD[i]); }`   if the number is in the fibonacci sequence, `fib(arrD[i])` will return true, and the number will be `.push`ed into the `newArr`

**Using a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)**

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,8,3,8];

let sqrt = (num) => { return num > 0 && Math.sqrt(num) % 1 === 0; };

let fib = (num) => { return sqrt(5 * Math.pow(num,2) + 4) || sqrt(5 * Math.pow(num,2) - 4); };

function fibArr(arr) {
   arrD = Array.from(new Set(arr));
   let newArr = [];
   for ( let i = 0; i < arrD.length; i++ ) {
      if(fib(arrD[i])) { newArr.push(arrD[i]); }   
   }
   return newArr;
}

console.log(fibArr(arr));
```

**OR using [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)**

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,8,3,8];

let sqrt = (num) => { return num > 0 && Math.sqrt(num) % 1 === 0; };

let fib = (num) => { return sqrt(5 * Math.pow(num,2) + 4) || sqrt(5 * Math.pow(num,2) - 4); };

function fibArr(arr) {
    arrD = Array.from(new Set(arr));
    let newArr = arrD.filter(function(arrD){
    return fib(arrD);
})
   return newArr;
}

console.log(fibArr(arr));
```